# How to configure Ecto at runtime?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Following the [setup instructions](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto), I have the following Ecto configuration in my `config/config.exs` file :

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: "postgresql://postgres@localhost/myrepo",
  size: 20
```

If my understanding is correct, the `config.exs` is evaluated at compile-time.

Is there a way to do this configuration step at runtime ?

This is for an app which will be distributed as a compiled binary (via `exrm`). The end-user should be able to customize the database url and pool size via flags or environment variables, not by editing `sys.config`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loading from the system is possible by using `{:system, "KEY" }` e.g.:

```
config :my_app Repo
   url: {:system, "DATABASE_URL" },
   size: {:system, "DATABASE_POOL_SIZE" }
```

instead

```
config :my_app, Repo,
   url: "ecto://postgres:postgres@localhost/ecto_simple",
   size: 20
```

In this case you set up Ecto to use the system properties. Of course, a user has to configure it.

Comment: It's worth noting that if Mix releases are used, there's a new approach consisting in using a file where to configure runtime options: https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-runtime-configuration

Answer (score 3):

Using `{:system, "KEY"}` has been [deprecated in Ecto v3](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/commit/804e37c373afab5b3d195b8b10945a1a6641a149).

Instead, you are advised to define an [`init/2` callback function](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:init/2) within your Repo module to set runtime config:

```
def init(_type, config) do
  config = Keyword.put(config, :url, System.get_env("DATABASE_URL"))

  {:ok, config}
end
```

Using a runtime `init/2` function allows configuration to be read from more than just environment variables.