# How do I populate my Elixir config from runtime variables?

Tags: erlang, environment-variables, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to make my Elixir app get some of the config values during startup instead of reading the hardcoded entries from `sys.config`.

My current approach would be to have an OTP app that boots first and translates some of the `System.get_env()` results into `Application.put_env()` calls.

This looks pretty convoluted, so I'm curious if there is a better (standard) solution to such tasks.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283387/how-to-configure-ecto-at-runtime

Comment: thanks @tkowal! somehow I assumed that `{:system, "VAR"}` syntax corresponds to compile time parsing

Comment: Actually they do. There is blog post that explains how to deal with it nicely: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/05/how-to-config-environment-variables-with-elixir-and-exrm/